# PHP - how to search in both key and values for a string?

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm trying to find a string in CSS that's been converted to an array. What I want to do is find a string within the key or value of array, and show the css block.

I tried for a few hours but cant make any progress.

Any suggestions?

Code is generated using this PHP css parser at http://pastebin.com/fstMwd3q

Example below is find css block with string "upload" and show each of the css blocks that has that. Another example is find all css that has inline-block.

```
Array
(

    [.qq-upload-cancel] => Array
        (
            [font-size] => 11px
        )

    [.qq-upload-failed-text] => Array
        (
            [display] => none
        )

    [.qq-upload-fail .qq-upload-failed-text] => Array
        (
            [display] => inline
        )

    [span.iconmorehelp] => Array
        (
            [display] => inline-block
            [height] => 18px
            [width] => 18px
        )

    [a.iconmoreinfo] => Array
        (
            [height] => 18px
            [width] => 18px
            [display] => inline-block
            [margin-top] => 3px
            [margin-right] => 3px
        )
)
```

**Here's my code based on solution from willium below. If someone can make this simpler, please post!! **

```
foreach($array as $key=>$item) {
    global $needle;
    $found = false;
    $result1='';
    $result2='';

    $result1=$key;
    if(strpos($key, $needle)) {
        $found=true;
    }
    foreach($item as $key=>$value) {        
        $result2.= $key . ":";
        $result2.= $value .":\n";
        if(strpos($key, $needle) || strpos($value, $needle)) {
            $found=true;
        }

    }
    if($found) echo "<pre>" . $result1 . "\n{\n" . $result2 . "\n}\n\n </pre>";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do a string search for multidimensional arrays within an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719968/how-can-i-do-a-string-search-for-multidimensional-arrays-within-an-object)

Comment: did you tried with array walk function?

Comment: Why have you opened another question the same as your last one without answering the comments? People are trying to help, but you won't give the information they are asking for. -1.

Comment: Also, that is not a valid array. eg you cannot have an array index called .qq-upload-failed-text

Comment: I got this code using this php parser. http://pastebin.com/fstMwd3q

Comment: @deceze yeah i should erase that prior one. this question is closer to what i want. i've been at it for few hours and trying to figure out.

Comment: @deceze you can if it is '.qq-upload-failed-text', but not without the quotes.

Comment: Can you post the code that generated the array you gave posted?

Comment: @vascowhite this is propably `print_r()` output so it's valid ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can loop through the array and parse for key value with a foreach loop.

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key=>$value) {
        echo $key;
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! and it was so simple!!! man... took me whole day. And I got it working! at least first part. now to tackle going through all the files to search. This is awesome. thanks!

Comment: @scott what do you want to return? All css rules that contain the text you are searching for?

Comment: @vascowhite Yes I need to find css rules for text.

Comment: The whole rule, or just the name?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for you to achieve what you want is to add another method to your cssparser class.

```
/**
*    Returns an arrray of rule names containing
*    the text in $cssFrag
**/ 
function findByCss($cssFrag)
{
    $result = null;
    $cssFrag = strtolower($cssFrag);
    $css = $this->css;
    foreach($css as $selector => $rule){
        if(stripos($selector, $cssFrag)){
            $result[] = $selector;
        } else {
           foreach($rule as $key => $property){
               if(stripos($key, $cssFrag) || stripos($property, $cssFrag)){
                   $result[] = $selector;
               }
           }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then you can do `$rules = $cssparser->findByCss('inline');`

Comment: sorry... i shoiuld be more clear. Can this also search within the class name or class id? right now, the code you suggested can only search the rules (my fault there for not understanding).

Comment: It will now search the whole css rule including class/id name.

Comment: awesome! thanks so much vascowhite! I was able to combine the css parser code and a directory scanning code to parse all css files within directory/subdirectories and show the css blocks. freaking awesome!  the css parser is from http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1289-PHP-CSS-parser-class.html and the directory scanner from http://www.designerstalk.com/forums/programming/8005-php-finding-occurences-string-file.html

Comment: willium answered it first and i accepted his solution already. so hope you dont mind but i think both solutions are brilliant. yours is more integrated and that's awesome.

Comment: That's fine, but just be aware that SO is about rewarding the most useful answer, not the first. Nobody gets offended by people changing accepted answers if a better one is posted later. This site is all about good questions and good answers.